# How to ignore Characters while matching in vim

Tags: vim, match

I'm trying Vim (gvim on windows 7) since past few days and must say its very interesting though it does have a steep learning curve.

I have a decently built _vimrc file now, all thanks to this forum, but am looking for a specific pattern ignore technique.

Suppose, in a text file I have a string like so:

```
10000000c9abcdef
```

and in the same file I have the same string, just separated with : at every 2 characters like so,

```
10:00:00:00:c9:ab:cd:ef
```

Or, I have a line such as,

```
hostname portname switchname
```

as well as

```
hostname_portname_switchname
```

how can I make vim match  `10000000c9abcdef` with `10:00:00:00:c9:ab:cd:ef` and match `hostname portname switchname` with `hostname_portname_switchname` ?

As of now, if I place the cursor below `10:00:00:00:c9:ab:cd:ef` and hit *, it just highlights and matches the `10:00:00:00:c9:ab:cd:ef`, but how can I make it match `10000000c9abcdef` ? or `hostname_portname_switchname` with `hostname portname switchname` ?

Basically, I want vim to ignore the Non Word Characters ( assuming that non word characters would be a space, tab, :, ::, comma, colon, semicolon etc.)

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the match with `*`, you can modify the search pattern to change any literal non-keyword character (`\k\@!.`) to match any non-keyword, optionally (`\?`):

```
:let @/ = substitute(@/, '\k\@!.', '\\%(\\k\\@!.\\)\\?', 'g')
```

To also make this work with `_`, you have to either adapt the regular expression, or `:set iskeyword-=_`.

Answer (score 0):

Not too easily. You would define a function that would extract the word under cursor, remove any non-alphanumerics, insert `[^a-z0-9]*` between each character, then search on that; and then map `#` and `/` to call that function. It would however also match `hos - tnamep; ort - names - witch - name`.